# Как организовать подгрузку модальных окон в зависимости от id элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

У меня есть сайт с каталогом. Хочу сделать модальные окна для него, чтобы при клике на карточку с товаром всплывала доп. информация с 3 доп. фото. Уже присвоил каждому товару id, но никак не могу придумать скрипт.

Полная версия на [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Incognitus/pen/QBMPWL)

```js
$(".clothes_js").click(function() {
  $(".cl-item").hide();
  $(".clothes").show("fast");
  $(".boots").show("fast");
});

$(".hzt_js").click(function() {
  $(".cl-item").hide();
  $(".cl-item.ph").show("fast");
  $(".cl-item.sl").show("fast");
  $(".cl-item.tr").show("fast");
});

$(".pled_js").click(function() {
  $(".cl-item").hide();
  $(".cl-item.pled").show("fast");
});

function catalog() {
    document.getElementById("cg").style.display = "grid";
    document.getElementById("cl").style.display = "grid";
    document.getElementById("back-btn").style.visibility = "visible";
};

$(".back-btn").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".cg-dummy").offset().top},
        'slow');
});

// FLickity Start

$('.slideshow').flickity({
  // options
  cellAlign: 'center',
  contain: true,
  wrapAround: true, 
  autoPlay: 5000, 
  prevNextButtons: false,
  cellSelector: '.ss-item'
});
```

```css
/*----------------------------------------*\
 #ESSENTIALS
\*----------------------------------------*/

:root {
 --dark-blue: #34495e;
 --green: #27ae60;
 --shadow: 0 0 30px 1px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8);
 --b_green: 3px solid var(--green);
 --orange: #e67e22;
 --gradient : linear-gradient(to bottom right, #00e5ff, #2ecc71);
 --gradient_shadow: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3))
}


/*------------------
 !COLORS
------------------*/

.blue         { background-color: #1078A4; }

.biruza       { background-color: #00939A; }

.siren        { background-color: #C13C8D; }

.malina       { background-color: #E76F77; }

.corall       { background-color: #E44440; }

.an-dark-blue { background-color: #24204A; }

.olive        { background-color: #635836; }

.baklajan    { background-color: #503944; }

.grey         { background-color: grey;    }

.cream { 
 background-color: #E9C4AA;
 color: var(--dark-blue);
}

.gradient { 
 background: var(--gradient);
 color: var(--dark-blue);
}

.white {
 background-color: white;
 color: var(--dark-blue);
}

.yellow {
 background-color: #FFCE65;
 color: var(--dark-blue);
}


/*------------------
 !ANIMATIONS
------------------*/

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
 0% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1)
 }

 50% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 0);
 }

 100% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1);
 }
}
@-o-keyframes pulse {
 0% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1)
 }

 50% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 0);
 }

 100% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
 0% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1)
 }

 50% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 0);
 }

 100% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1);
 }
}
@keyframes pulse {
 0% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1)
 }

 50% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 0);
 }

 100% {
  border: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 1);
 }
}


/*------------------
 !MAIN
------------------*/

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 /*font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;*/
 text-align: center;
}

html, body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
}

.dummy {
 visibility: hidden;
}






/*----------------------------------------*\
 #ESSENTIALS
\*----------------------------------------*/

.navbar {
 position             : relative;
 top                  : 0;
 display              : grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 justify-items        : center;
 align-items          : center;
 width                : 100%;
 padding              : 10px;
 background-color     : var(--dark-blue);
}

.home-btn a img {
 margin    : 0;
 border    : 3px solid white;
 min-width : 180px;
 min-height: 80px;
}

tr > td {
 padding    : 3px 0;
 text-align : left;
 color      : var(--green);
 font-weight: bold;
}

td img {
 float       : right;
 margin-right: 5px;
 width       : 20px;
 height      : 20px;
}


/*------------------
 !SLIDESHOW
------------------*/

.slideshow {
 background: var(--dark-blue);
 position  : relative;
}

.ss-item {
 width       : 100%;
 height      : 80vh;
 margin-right: 0;
 background  : var(--green);
 font-size   : 1.25em;
}

.ss-item:nth-child(1) {
 background         : url(../img/ss1.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size    : cover;
 background-position: center center;
}

.ss-item:nth-child(2) {
 background         : url(../img/ss2.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size    : cover;
 background-position: center center;
}

.ss-item:nth-child(3) {
 background         : url(../img/ss3.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size    : cover;
 background-position: center center;
}

.ss-item:nth-child(4) {
 background         : url(../img/ss4.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size    : cover;
 background-position: center center;
}

.ss-item:nth-child(5) {
 background         : url(../img/ss5.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size    : cover;
 background-position: center center;
}

.ss-item__text {
 position: absolute;
 left    : 50px;
 bottom  : 50px;
 width   : 90%;
}

.ss-item__h1 {
 margin : 0;
 padding: 10px;
 float  : left;
 display: inline-block;
 color  : white/*var(--green)*/;
 /*background: var(--dark-blue);*/
}

.ss-item__p {
 margin      : 0;
 padding     : 10px;
 width       : 80%;
 float       : left;
 clear       : left;
 display     : inline-block;
 color       : white/*var(--green)*/;
 text-align  : left;
 /*background: var(--dark-blue);*/
}


.slideshow .flickity-page-dots {
 bottom : 0.5em;
 opacity: 1;
}

.slideshow .flickity-page-dots .dot {
 width     : 10px;
 height    : 10px; 
 background: #ccc;
 border    : 2px solid transparent;
}

.slideshow .flickity-page-dots .dot.is-selected {
 background: #76ff03;
}


/*------------------
 !INFO
------------------*/

.info {
 display           :grid;
 grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
 margin            : 20px;
 box-shadow        : var(--shadow);
}

.info__text {
 background  : var(--dark-blue);
 color       : var(--green);
 text-align  : center;
 font-size   : 1.2em;
 border-top  : 3px solid var(--green);
 margin      : 0;
 padding     : 20px;
 /*box-shadow: var(--shadow);*/
}

.info__map iframe {
 height: 100%;
 width : 100%;
}






/*----------------------------------------*\
 #CATALOG STUFF
\*----------------------------------------*/


/*------------------
 !DUMMY
------------------*/


.cg-dummy {
 position           : relative;
 width              : 100%;
 height             : 500px;
 background         : url(../img/catalog.jpg);
 background-size    : cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-color   : #000;
 box-shadow         : var(--shadow);
 box-sizing         : border-box;
 display            : -webkit-flex;
 display            : -moz-flex;
 display            : -ms-flex;
 display            : -o-flex;
 display            : flex;
 justify-content    : center;
 align-items        : center;
 margin             : 30px auto;
 cursor             : pointer;
 transition         : opacity .7s ease-in-out;
}

.cg-dummy:hover {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.cg-dummy h1 {
 font-weight: bold;
 color      : var(--green);
 padding    : 10px;
 border     : 3px solid var(--green);
 transition : opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.cg-dummy:hover h1 { opacity: .7; }


/*------------------
 !CATEGORIES
------------------*/

.cg {
 display: none;
 grid-gap: 20px;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(382px, 1fr));
 grid-template-rows: 1fr;
 margin: 0 20px;
}


.cg-h1 {
 display      : none;
 text-align   : center;
 font-size    : 2.5em;
 color        : var(--green);
 margin       : 20px auto; 
 cursor       : pointer;
 padding      : 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

 
.cg-item {
 background: var(--dark-blue);
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 border-bottom: 3px solid var(--green);
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8)/*var(--shadow)*/;
}

.cg-item:focus {
 border-right: var(--b_green);
 border-left: var(--b_green);
 border-top: var(--b_green);
}

.cg-item h1 {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 2.3em;
 color: var(--green);
}

.cg-item:nth-child(1) h1::before {
 content: "";
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;
   left: -70px;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   background: url(../svg/fashion.svg);
   -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
   background-size: 50px 50px;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}

.cg-item:nth-child(2) h1::before {
 content: "";
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;
   left: -70px;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
 background: url(../svg/dish.svg);
   -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
   background-size: 50px 50px;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}

.cg-item:nth-child(3) h1::before {
 content: "";
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;
   left: -70px;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
 background: url(../svg/armchair.svg);
   -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
   background-size: 50px 50px;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}

.back-btn {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 5%;
 right: 5%;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: 2px solid var(--green);
 background: var(--dark-blue);
 z-index: 160;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: var(--orange);
 visibility: hidden;
}


/*------------------
 !CATALOG
------------------*/

.cl {
 display: none;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 340px);
 grid-template-rows: 1fr;
 grid-gap: 20px;
 justify-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
 align-content: center;
 margin: 20px 0;
}

.cl::after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}

.cl-item {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 70px) 70px 15px;
   grid-template-columns: 320px;
   box-shadow: var(--shadow);
   width: 320px;
   height: 364px;
   /*float: left;*/
}

.cl-item::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.cl-item img {
 grid-row: 1/5;
 display: block;
 height: 100%; 
 width: 100%; 
 object-fit: fill;
}

.cl-item__info {
 grid-row: 6/7;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

 .cl-item__color {
  display: block;
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
  color: white /*var(--orange)*/;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
 }

 .cl-item__size {
  display: block;
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: var(--dark-blue);
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--orange);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
 }

.cl-item p {
 /*display: inline;*/
 grid-row: 5/6;
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
 background-color: var(--dark-blue);
 border-top: 4px solid var(--green);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 19.2px;
 color: var(--green);
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}


.clothes img, .boots img {
  /*width: 70%;*/
  object-fit: contain;
}






/*----------------------------------------*\
 #ESSENTIALS
\*----------------------------------------*/


/*------------------
 !MEDIA
------------------*/


@media (min-width: 1280px) {

 .info {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 }

 .info__text {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 3px solid var(--green);
 }
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {

 body {
  font-size: 12px;
 }

 .ss-item__text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom    : 30px;
  left    : 30px;
  width   : 90%;
  font-size: .8em;
 }
 .info {
  display           :grid;
  grid-template-rows: 300px 1fr;
  margin            : 20px;
  box-shadow        : var(--shadow);
 }

 .cg {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  margin: 0;
 }
 

 .cg-item h1 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
 }
 
 .cg-item:nth-child(3) h1::before {
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: -60px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: url(../svg/armchair.svg);
    -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
 }
 
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
 .navbar {
     grid-template-columns: 1fr;
     grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
   }
  
   .dummy {
     display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 361px) {

 .navbar-number {
  margin: 20px auto;
 }

 .cg-dummy {
  height: 200px;
 }

 .ss-item__text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom  : 30px;
  left    : 20px;
  width   : 90%;
  font-size: .7em;
 }

 .cg-item {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  font-size: 1.2em;
 }

 .cg-item img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

 }

 .cl-item {
  margin: 20px auto;
 }



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>TextileToday</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=9">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flickity.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/myScript.js?v=9"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <nav class="navbar">

   
   <div class="info-tb  dummy">

    <table>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20" alt=""></td>
        <td>84955100075</td> 
      </tr>


      <tr>
       <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20" alt=""></td>
        <td>@Textile2day</td> 
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20" alt=""></td>
        <td>info.torgservice@bk.ru</td> 
      </tr>

    </table>

   </div>


   <div class="home-btn">
    <a href="#home"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
   </div>
   

   <div class="info-tb__header">

    <table>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="svg/telephone.svg" alt=""></td>
        <td>84955100075</td> 
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td><img src="svg/instagram.svg" alt=""></td>
        <td>@Textile2day</td> 
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td><img src="svg/email.svg" alt=""></td>
        <td>info.torgservice@bk.ru</td> 
      </tr>

    </table>

   </div>


 </nav>
 





 <section class="slideshow">


  <div class="ss-item">
   <div class="ss-item__text">
    <h1 class="ss-item__h1">Новое поколение</h1>
    <p class="ss-item__p">Велсофт — это синтетика нового поколения. Ткань называют также микрофиброй. Страна рождения – Япония. Именно здесь, на островах высоких технологий, в 1976 году был разработан способ изготовления уникальных, ультратонких волокон, диаметр которых не превышает 0,06 мм</p>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="ss-item">
   <div class="ss-item__text">
    <h1 class="ss-item__h1">Комфорт</h1>
    <p class="ss-item__p">Велсофт создан для домашнего комфорта и уюта. Её пушистый, мягкий ворс напоминает велюр, но отличается особой шелковистостью и нежностью. Изделия из этого материала дарят и взрослым, и детям ощущения особого домашнего тепла и покоя</p>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="ss-item">
   <div class="ss-item__text">
    <h1 class="ss-item__h1">Дышащая ткань</h1>
    <p class="ss-item__p">Наличие достаточно длинного и воздушного ворса, необыкновенно тёплого и приятного на ощупь, приводит к тому, что изделие почти мгновенно достигает температуры человеческого тела, в последующем сохраняя полученное тепло. Одежда из велсофта препятствует перегреву даже в очень тёплом помещении</p>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="ss-item">
   <div class="ss-item__text">
    <h1 class="ss-item__h1">Безопасность</h1>
    <p class="ss-item__p">Велсофт производят в полном соответствии с нормами международной системы сертификации и тестирования изделий из текстиля Эко Текс, что делает его пригодным для производства домашней и детской одежды</p>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="ss-item">
   <div class="ss-item__text">
    <h1 class="ss-item__h1">Гипоалергенность</h1>
    <p class="ss-item__p">Микрофибра — гипоаллергенная ткань, состоящая из полимерных и натуральных волокон, в том числе нейлона, полиэстера, хлопка или вискозы. Ткань широко применяется при производстве одежды, мебели, в промышленности. В ее основе — ультратонкие волокна, в 10 раз меньше диаметра волокна натурального шелка</p>
   </div>
  </div>


 </section>





 
 <div class="cg-dummy" id="cg-dummy" onclick="catalog()">
  <h1 id="dummy__h1">Каталог</h1>
 </div> 
 

 <div class="cg" id="cg">


  <button class="cg-item  сlothes_js">
   <h1>Одежда</h1>
  </button>


  <button class="cg-item  hzt_js">
   <h1>Хозтовары</h1>
  </button>


  <button class="cg-item  pled_js">
   <h1>Товары для дома</h1>
  </button>


 </div>


 <div class="back-btn" id="back-btn"><img src="svg/upload.svg" alt=""></div>


 <div class="cl" id="cl">
  
  <!--------------------------
   ТОВАРЫ ДЛЯ ДОМА
  -------------------------->

  <!------------
   DPLED
  ------------->

  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A000">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled1.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color cream">Кремовый</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
    </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A001">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled2.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color blue">Голубой</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A002">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled3.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color biruza">Бирюза</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item pled" id="A003">
   <img src="img/dpled/dpled4.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color siren">Сирень</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size">150x200cm, 200x220cm</div>
   </div>
   <p>Плед из велсофта</p>
  <div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Набор: полотенце, прихватка, варежка</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item ph" id="C002">
   <img src="img/hzt/ph2.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color gradient">Принт</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Набор: полотенце, прихватка, варежка</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item ph" id="C003">
   <img src="img/hzt/ph3.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color gradient">Принт</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Набор: полотенце, прихватка, варежка</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item ph" id="C004">
   <img src="img/hzt/ph4.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color gradient">Принт</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Набор: полотенце, прихватка, варежка</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item ph" id="C005">
   <img src="img/hzt/ph5.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color gradient">Принт</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Набор: полотенце, прихватка, варежка</p>
  </div>


  <!------------
   SL
  ------------->

  <div class="cl-item sl" id="C006">
   <img src="img/hzt/sl1.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color gradient">Принт</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Набор салфеток 2шт/уп</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item sl" id="C007">
   <img src="img/hzt/sl2.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color gradient">Принт</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Набор салфеток 2шт/уп</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item sl" id="C008">
   <img src="img/hzt/sl3.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color gradient">Принт</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Набор салфеток 2шт/уп</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item sl" id="C009">
   <img src="img/hzt/sl4.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color gradient">Принт</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Набор салфеток 2шт/уп</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item sl" id="C010">
   <img src="img/hzt/sl5.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color gradient">Принт</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Набор салфеток 2шт/уп</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item sl" id="C011">
   <img src="img/hzt/sl6.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color gradient">Принт</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Набор салфеток 2шт/уп</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item sl" id="C012">
   <img src="img/hzt/sl7.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color gradient">Принт</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Набор салфеток 2шт/уп</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item sl" id="C013">
   <img src="img/hzt/sl8.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color gradient">Принт</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Набор салфеток 2шт/уп</p>
  </div>


  <!------------
   TR
  ------------->


  <div class="cl-item tr" id="C014">
   <img src="img/hzt/tr1.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color gradient"></div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Салфетки из микрофибры</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item tr" id="C015">
   <img src="img/hzt/tr2.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color grey">Серый</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Тряпка ХПП</p>
  </div>


  <div class="cl-item tr" id="C016">
   <img src="img/hzt/tr3.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="cl-item__info">
    <div class="cl-item__color grey">Серый</div>
    <div class="cl-item__size"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Тряпка ХПП</p>
  </div>
 </div>


 <!------------
  INFO
 ------------->
 
 <section class="info">


   <div class="info__map">
    <iframe src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/?um=constructor%3A8d0ea1ca531130bb8e37b9c49800ce1ebd18d746f2053b9ae6ab150c6ee39a40&amp;source=constructor"  frameborder="0"></iframe>
   </div>

   
   <div class="info__text">
    <h1>О компании</h1>
    <p>
     Компания «Торгсервис» – современное предприятие, обеспечивающее производство текстильных изделий для дома. Это пледы, покрывала, детские конверты, салфетки и многое др. Компания выработала эффективную политику работы с поставщиками ткани из Китайской Народной Республики и их представительствами в России. Все изделия из велсофта, флиса, микрофибры изготавливаются  на нашем собственном производстве или в швейных цехах партнёров нашей компании. Товары могут расфасовываться и упаковываться, в том числе и под собственной торговой маркой клиента. Работа отдела дизайна позволяет нам менять коллекцию товаров несколько раз в год. Компания отгружает свою продукцию в федеральные и локальные торговые сети, а так же в крупные интернет-магазины.
    </p>
   </div>


 </section>

 <script src="js/myScript.js"></script>
 <script src="js/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<!-- (.cl-item>im id="0000"g.ph$+p{Lorem ipsum dolor.})*4 -->
```

Comment: А что сложного то ? Код скинь, помогу

Comment: Отследил элемент на который кликнул и сгенерировал модальку

Comment: @Netahaki добавил

Comment: @Netahaki а как сделать эту самую генерацию ?